# How to use cross_validation with curve_fit?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, cross-validation

I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to check models on my data.

Normally, I would have a function of several variables, here y_data is a function of 2 variables in x_data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x_data = np.array( [np.arange(10), np.arange(10)*-1+5] )
print( x_data )
```

> [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
>
> [ 5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4]]

```
y_data = np.arange(10) - 5
print( y_data )
```

> [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]

To fit the function, I just define it, and use `curve_fit`:

```
def lincomb( X, a, b ):
    x1 = X[0]
    x2 = X[1]
    return a*x1*x2 + b

popt, pcov = curve_fit( lincomb, x_data, y_data )
print( popt )
```

> [-0.17857143 -1.57142857]

The latter are the optimized values of the coefficients a and b in the function.

---

Now, I would like to use cross validation from `sklearn` to do the same fit. For this, I packed my function into a class to be used as an estimator, like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

class LinComb:
    def __init__( self, a=None, b=None ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def _lincomb_background(self, X, a, b):
        x1 = X[0]
        x2 = X[1]
        return a*x1*x2 + b

    def predict( self, X ):
        return self._lincomb_background( X, self.a, self.b )

    def fit( self, X, y ):
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        popt, pcov = curve_fit( self._lincomb_background, X, y )
        self.a = popt[0]
        self.b = popt[1]
        return self

    def get_params( self, deep=False ):
        return { 'a':self.a, 'b':self.b }

    def set_params( self, **parameters ):
        for parameter, value in parameters.intems():
            setattr( self, parameter, value )
        return self
```

When I then call the cross validation, I get an error in dimensions:

```
cross_validate( LinComb(), x_data, y_data, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-e0ff8bb83213> in <module>
----> 1 cross_validate( LinComb(), x_data, y_data, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    215 
    216     """
--> 217     X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    218 
    219     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    228         else:
    229             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 230     check_consistent_length(*result)
    231     return result
    232 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    203     if len(uniques) > 1:
    204         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 205                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 10]
```

Indeed, the dimensions of x_data and y_data are:

```
print( x_data.shape, y_data.shape )
```

> (2, 10) (10,)

Still I do not understand why the dimensions work in the first, simple case, and how to achieve this cleanly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I had 2 errors in the dimensions. Since they were simultaneous, I wasn't able to trace them back easily. I will post the answer here, maybe it will be useful sometime.

---

**1. From the documentation**

Modifying the example in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) helped to trace back the dimension errors.

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, cross_val_score

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()

cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3)
sorted(cv_results.keys())

print( cv_results['test_score'] )
```

> [0.33150734 0.08022311 0.03531764]

Note that `cross_validation` needs the first dimensions to be the same:

```
print( X.shape, y.shape )
```

> (150, 10) (150,)

Note that with these new dimensions, the simple way to call `curve_fit` throws an error:

```
def lincomb( X, a, b ):
    x1 = X[0]
    x2 = X[1]
    return a*x1*x2 + b

popt, pcov = curve_fit( lincomb, x_data, y_data )
print( popt )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dedaa241e377> in <module>
      4     return a*x1*x2 + b
      5 
----> 6 popt, pcov = curve_fit( lincomb, x_data, y_data )
      7 print( popt )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    754         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    755         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 756         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    757         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    758         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    456     if transform is None:
    457         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 458             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    459     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    460         def func_wrapped(params):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (10,)
```

This can be solved by transposing again inside the call to `curve_fit`:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit( lincomb, x_data.T, y_data )
print( popt )
```

> [-0.17857143 -1.57142857]

---

**2. Class**

Using the new dimensions in `x_data` for `cross_validation` (using the class defined in the question) throws a different error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

class LinComb:
    def __init__( self, a=None, b=None ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def _lincomb_background(self, X, a, b):
        x1 = X[0]
        x2 = X[1]
        return a*x1*x2 + b

    def predict( self, X ):
        return self._lincomb_background( X, self.a, self.b )

    def fit( self, X, y ):
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        popt, pcov = curve_fit( self._lincomb_background, X, y )
        self.a = popt[0]
        self.b = popt[1]
        return self

    def get_params( self, deep=False ):
        return { 'a':self.a, 'b':self.b }

    def set_params( self, **parameters ):
        for parameter, value in parameters.intems():
            setattr( self, parameter, value )
        return self


cross_validate( LinComb(), x_data, y_data, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e0ff8bb83213> in <module>
----> 1 cross_validate( LinComb(), x_data, y_data, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    229             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    230             error_score=error_score)
--> 231         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    232 
    233     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    919             # remaining jobs.
    920             self._iterating = False
--> 921             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    512             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    513         else:
--> 514             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    515 
    516     except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-9-ff88060f1729> in fit(self, X, y)
     15     def fit( self, X, y ):
     16         from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
---> 17         popt, pcov = curve_fit( self._lincomb_background, X, y )
     18         self.a = popt[0]
     19         self.b = popt[1]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    754         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    755         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 756         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    757         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    758         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    456     if transform is None:
    457         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 458             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    459     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    460         def func_wrapped(params):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (8,)
```

---

**3. Dimension error inside the class**

This error is coming from `curve_fit`, not `cross_validation`, and must be corrected inside the class, in **both** functions calling the model `_lincomb_background()`, that is, both in `fit()` and `predict()`. The modified class is:

```
class LinComb:
    def __init__( self, a=None, b=None ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def _lincomb_background(self, X, a, b):
        x1 = X[0]
        x2 = X[1]
        return a*x1*x2 + b

    def predict( self, X ):
        return self._lincomb_background( X.T, self.a, self.b ) # Call with transposed X!

    def fit( self, X, y ):
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        popt, pcov = curve_fit( self._lincomb_background, X.T, y ) # Call with transposed X!
        self.a = popt[0]
        self.b = popt[1]
        return self

    def get_params( self, deep=False ):
        return { 'a':self.a, 'b':self.b }

    def set_params( self, **parameters ):
        for parameter, value in parameters.intems():
            setattr( self, parameter, value )
        return self
```

With these two modified calls, `cross_validation` works as expected:

```
cross_validate( LinComb(), x_data, y_data, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' )
```

> {'fit_time': array([0.00105524, 0.00051618, 0.0004158 , 0.00040078, 0.00039887]),
>    'score_time': array([0.00158715, 0.0001812 , 0.00017715, 0.00017595, 0.00017548]),
>    'test_score': array([-12.89      ,  -0.29918379,  -3.82378685,  -2.72051908,
>            -7.25      ])}

---

**4. Summary**

a) First check that the dimensions for `cross_validation()` are correct

b) Then adjust dimensions inside the class, in the call to `curve_fit()`

c) Lastly adjust dimensions inside the class, in `predict()`